# how to extract certain text from file?

Tags: file, text, extract

i want to extract certain section of the text file. my input file:

```
-- num cell port function safe [ccell disval rslt]
   "17 (BC_1, CLK, input, X)," &
   "16 (BC_1, OC_NEG, input, X), " &-- Merged input/
   " 8 (BC_1, D(8), input, X)," &  -- cell 16 @ 1 -> Hi-Z
   " 7 (BC_1, Q(1), output3, X, 16, 1, Z)," &
   " 0 (BC_1, Q(8), output3, X, 16, 1, Z)";
```

and i need the output to be as such:

```
num cell port function safe ccell
   17 BC_1 CLK input X 
   16 BC_1 OC_NEG input X  
   16 BC_1 * control 1 
    8 BC_1 D8 input X   
    7 BC_1 Q1 output3 X 16 1  
    0 BC_1 Q8 output3 X 16 1
```

so far i tried below code but it gave index error. pls advise.

```
import re
lines=open("input.txt",'r').readlines()

for line in lines:
    a=re.findall(r'\w+',line)
    print re.findall(r'\w+',line)
    print a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6]
```

i'm using python 2.6.6 and error as below:

```
['num', 'cell', 'port', 'function', 'safe', 'ccell', 'disval', 'rslt']
num cell port function safe ccell disval
['17', 'BC_1', 'CLK', 'input', 'X']
17 BC_1 CLK input X
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ctee1\Desktop\pyparsing\outputparser.py", line 39, in <module>
    print a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What language is this for? Can we get a copy of the exact exception message?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(disval|rslt)//; s/(.)--.*/\1/; s/[^[:alnum:]_]//; s/ +$//'
```